# NGINX setup for separate Vue Frontend and Express Backend

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, vue.js

I am wondering about the proper nginx setup when deploying a vue frontend separately from an express backend - not separately in terms of servers or domains, but in terms of how they are served.

During development, I use `npm serve` in the vue directory, and to build a production build, it is generated via `npm run build`. The resulting `dist` folder should be served, and my question is how this is done when the backend is on the same server.

Let's say for the backend, express is exposing routes. **Should nginx be in front of express here?**
The vue front end is calling those routes, but the static files need to be served. According to the [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#previewing-locally) this can be done using `serve`. Is this intended for production? And then again, should nginx be in front of this?

I am wondering, because the route would then be:

> Browser Request -> Nginx to Vue Frontend -> Vue Frontend -> Nginx to
>   Backend

Is this a suitable approach or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: A completely suitable approach to use nginx to proxy pass requests to express from your vue front end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should nginx be in front of express here?

Yes, it is a very good idea.

You have to use a distinct set of URLs for Vue and Express, so Nginx, while looking at request URL, will be able to understand what to do: give a Vue file or proxy to Express. Nginx has a variety of options how to classify incoming requests: by different hostnames, by paths, by combination of both, etc.

For example, prepend all your Express routes with `/api/` path prefix. Then configure nginx like this:

*This is not production ready configuration, I'm just trying to give a hint what you should look for in nginx docs*

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomainname.com;

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;  # port that Express serves,
                                       # better change to UNIX domain socket
  }

  location / {
    root /vue_root/dist;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh this makes sense! So for calls to ‘/‘, vue will be served and vue talks to ‘/api’ where express is sitting. Thanks a lot!